# Why Doesn't my Code Update The database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

look at these two codes

1. First:

   ```
   Slide _Slide = DataContext.Slides.SingleOrDefault(rec => rec.Id == _SlideObj.Id);
   _Slide = _SlideObj;            
   DataContext.SaveChanges();
   ```
2. Second:

   ```
   Slide _Slide = DataContext.Slides.SingleOrDefault(rec => rec.Id == _SlideObj.Id);
   _Slide.Title = _SlideObj.Title;
   _Slide.Description = _SlideObj.Description;
   DataContext.SaveChanges();
   ```

The first code does not update the database but the second updates. Why? How can I change  my code to do update operation in first method? (I like to use first method)

Comment: Remove the line `_Slide = _SlideObj;` as it's overwriting the value and makes the first line totally meaningless. Maybe you meant `_SlideObj = _Slide;`?

Comment: aa no, _SlideObj contain new value that i want to store them in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no update because you didn't change anything. In the first case, you just changed `_Slide` to point to a different Slide.

Comment: @Ali pretty much: your second block of code **is** the solution.

Comment: is there any other solution in accessible? i think if i have an object with many field, this method is not good,agree?

Comment: There is pretty much only one method - change the fields that you need to change.

Comment: @Ali: To avoid copying the properties one by one you can use `DataContext.Slides.ApplyCurrentValues(_SlideObj)` or in EF 4.1: `context.Entry(_Slide).CurrentValues.SetValues(_SlideObj)`. It updates all scalar and complex properties but not navigation properties. For those you have to do the update manually.

Comment: @Slauma ,thanks my friend.your comment is great.thanks again for you useful help.

Answer (score 5):

The first only changes the value of a *variable* to be a different reference. It doesn't actually update the *object* in any way. The data-context is tracking the **object**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the first approach is by design and has nothing to do with the framework you're using.

By calling:
_Slide = _SlideObj;
you are telling _Slide to point on _SlideObj instead, but in-memory, the Title and Description properties for the previous pointer to _Slider remain unchanged.

Therefore, this is normal behavior.